# Vector parallel to Parametric Line

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, parametric

Find a constant vector parallel to the line given parametrically by:

$$x = 1 - a$$
$$y = 2 + 3a$$
$$z = 1 + a$$

I made $a$ the subject and worked out the equation of a line represented by this as $r = (-i + 2j + k) + a(i + 3j + k)$. This means a constant vector parallel to the line would be $i + 3j + k$.

Is this correct ?

Comment: Review your question for correctness.

Comment: What do you want me to do ? I wrote down all my working

Comment: It is correct :)

Comment: Thank you buddy :)

Comment: $(x,y,z) = (1,2,1) + a (-1, 3, 1) $ This means the vector parallel to the line is $(-1, 3, 1) = - i + 3 j + k$

Comment: Silly me, when I rearranged I rearranged incorrectly. My bad!